# Change NFC SAK Hard Coded to 08h

Tags: nfc

I am trying to copy some NFC card; however the SAK returned is always 08h using the command `nfc-list`. However looking through the actual content of the card, I can see that the byte associated to the SAK is different (88h).

After making a full copy of the card, doing a full copy of both shows the exact same content, except when doing `nfc-list` the SAK of the newly copied card displays 88h instead of 08h as the original card does.

Is there a way to emulate or circumvent this issue in order to make both cards indiscernable one from another ?

Comment: I know next to nothing about NFC beyond what I've just read [here](https://www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/nfc-tag-initiation-sequence/), but there it says `SAK` is generated in response to a `SELECT` command, and that bit 6 (the one that's different between `08` and `88`) indicates whether the card supports MiFARE or not... are the two cards exactly the same? Could one support MiFARE and the other not?

Comment: @TripeHound No, the cards are not exactly the same and it is the way it's meant to be. As one is a card used in production, and the other one is a rewritable card; the purpose of this card is to completely clone the original card. The rewritable card returns anything that is written on byte 6; however the original card returns ALWAYS 08h no matter what happens to be on byte 6.